# CRM 2011 multithreading the inserts using an organization service proxy per thread

Tags: multithreading, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

My scenario is:

1. We have on premise CRM 2011.
2. I have a process that runs for a long time, does many inserts / thousands could take 5-30 minutes

Created a windows service that will run asynch this process

I created "x" number of threads that each has its own organization service proxy that will do inserts in parallel

3. We have 4.0 .net framework installed

Outcome is:

I can see 40% to 50% improvement with about 10 threads.

More than this number of concurrent threads will not help.

I wonder what settings are preventing the threads to run in parallel and how could those settings be set?

in the windows service app.config I tried this setting with no improvement:

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
<add address = "*" maxconnection = "100" />
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

I guess WCF organization service will create a session for each service proxy I have and it can handle more than 10?

Comment: So with 10 threads running what is your total creates per second? Are there sync plugins that execute during create? Do you have workflows or async plugins on create? If so, they could be putting load on the system if the Async Service is running on the web server. What does SQL performance look like?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, multi-threading only can get you so far.  At some point in time, the web server is processing the requests as fast as it can (Plugins can also be a rather large bottle neck if they are executing as a part of the transaction..  I'd check the performance of the webserver and the database server while you're hitting it, to see if any of those are the bottle neck.

If you're on rollup 12+, you'll get far better performance batching your transactions into an [Execute Multiple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863604(v=crm.5).aspx).

I also hope you are not creating a new thread for each record to insert/update, and consequentially a new IOrganizationService as well.  Consider giving 10-100 records to a thread at a time, and let it process through all of those.

Comment: We have on-premise CRM and both crm and web services/windows services are hosted on the same machine, the network traffic benefit of using Execute Multiple is minimum. Per one of my colleagues test  it is almost no benefit for Inserts. Whe I tried with a shared thread safe proxy I was not seeing a benefit and I guess the 85% of the times the calls were serialized and not executed in parallel.

Comment: @user3434916, just to ensure you're not getting any threading, add some logging, each time a request is made, log it.  Each time a request finishes, log it.  This will allow you to prove one way or the other if you truly are getting multi-threading or not.